# Why does using a view to draw my canvas result in a NPE?

Tags: java, android

I have a bitmap and storing it inside my canvas object.

Then I create an empty View and call draw on canvas.. but I keep getting a nullpointerexception, I'm not sure why.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bitmap myPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Bitmap newPic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myPic, 50, 50, true);
        Canvas myCanv = new Canvas(newPic);

        View myView = (View)findViewById(R.id.view1);
        myView.draw(myCanv);


    }
```

halp.

Comment: where you are calling `setContentView` ? you need to set layout for Activity using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout)` before using `findViewById` to get Views from layout of Activity

Comment: `View myView = (View)findViewById(R.id.view1);` before setting the layout to the activity

Comment: thanks guys. totally skipped my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can use `findViewById()` in an activity, you have to call `setContentView()` method to set the activity content. If you don't, `findViewById()` will always return null.

```
setContentView(R.id.yourlayoutid);
View myView = (View)findViewById(R.id.view1);
```